# Removing Gridlines in All Charts on All Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with the following code:

```
Sub RemoveGridlines()

Dim axs As Axes
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objCht As ChartObject

For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
            With objCht.Chart
                For Each axs In objCht.Chart
                    .Axes.HasMajorGridlines = False
                    .Axes.HasMinorGridlines = False
                Next axs
            End With
        Next objCht
Next ws

End Sub
```

And get hung up on `For Each axs In objCht.Chart` as an object mismatch. I tried adding `.axes` to the line but it won't proceed regardless. 
How can I get this to loop through each axis, chart, and worksheet? Even when I remove`.Chart` and remove `.Axes` from the subsequent lines I get `Method or data member not found`.

Comment: Can you try this>For Each axs In objCht< instead?

Comment: No dice. Still gets hung up when I remove `.Chart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, it is funny what was the real reason, but now the code works:

```
Sub RemoveGridlines2()

    Dim axs             As Axis
    Dim ws              As Worksheet
    Dim objCht          As ChartObject
    Dim k               As Chart

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
            Set k = Sheets(ws.Name).ChartObjects(objCht.Name).Chart
            For Each axs In k.Axes
                axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
                axs.HasMinorGridlines = False
            Next
            Set k = Nothing
        Next objCht
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Actually, if you change "AXES" to "AXIS" in your code in the "DIM" you may also get a working code :) 
Enjoy it! :D

EDIT: 
And that is how your code should look like:

```
Sub RemoveGridlines()

    Dim axs                 As Axis
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet
    Dim objCht              As ChartObject

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
            For Each axs In objCht.Chart.Axes
                axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
                axs.HasMinorGridlines = False
            Next axs
        Next objCht
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The caveat as that I'm trying to avoid using `.Axes(xlValue)` and `.Axes(xlCategory)`. And instead have a catch-all with the `For Each axs`.

Comment: I am not sure that you may loop through the axs with a for-each. Are the axs a collection?

Comment: The logic works as here: `Sub remove_gridlines()

    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim axs As Axis
    
    ' change chart name here
    Set cht = Sheets("Anesthesia").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
    
    For Each axs In cht.Axes
        axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
        axs.HasMinorGridlines = False
    Next
    

End Sub`

Comment: see edit, I have not tested it, but it seems to work.

Comment: That's throws a type mismatch.